# Continued Fractions and Pell's Equation's Smallest Solution

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

So beginning with the continued fraction $\quad \sqrt{D} = [ \;a_0;\overline {   \,a_1, \,\cdots, \phantom {!} a_n , } \cdots \;] \quad$ with the $a_1, \cdots,a_n,$ being the repeating portion.

In class, we showed that the $n$'th convergent ($ p_n / q_n )$ gives us the smallest solution to Pell's equation $p_n^2 - q_n^2 \sqrt{D} = 1$.
Now, I need to show that the smallest solution to Pell's equation $a^2 - b^2\sqrt{D} = \pm 1$ satisfies this relation: $a \le (a_0 + 1)^{2D}$
So far I have proved that each $a_i ≤ a_0$ where $a_0$ is the floor of $\sqrt{D}$ and that $n \le 2 D$.

Now I'm just stuck as to how to proceed.

Comment: To get a bar on top you use \overline{a,b,c} to get $\overline{a,b,c}$  Also to get the square root bar to extend over more than one character, put them in braces, so \sqrt{(D)} gives $\sqrt{(D)}$

Comment: Hope my mathjax-modifications are ok and I didn't mess your math. If you don't like something just roll-back!

Comment: induction: show $p_1 \leq a_0 + 1,$ then $p_2 \leq \left( a_0 +1\right)^2,$ $p_3 \leq \left( a_0 +1\right)^3,$